# Adding extra lines to trees with forest

Tags: forest, trees, edge

I have trying to draw trees using forest with consonants and vowels on different tiers.

With help from Sašo Živanović I managed to do this as in (1) in the following MWE.

I next wanted a tree with a link from the second $\mu$ to the k, as in (2) but this doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}       

(1)     \begin{forest}
         [,phantom,
            for level=4{fit=band}
            [$\omega$
                [$\sigma$  [$\mu$ [t] [a, l*=2]]]
                [$\sigma$  [$\mu$ [k] [a, l*=2]]]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}


(2)     \begin{forest}
         [,phantom,
            for level=4{fit=band}
            [$\omega$
                [$\sigma$  [$\mu$ [t] [a, l*=2]] [$\mu$, name=mu2]]
                [$\sigma$  [$\mu$ [k, name=k] [a, l*=2]]]
            ]
        ]
        \draw (mu2) -- (k);
    \end{forest}
\end {document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you please explain a bit more. The second mu seems to be connected to k, isn't it? For the purpose of the question you could give the nodes unique contents (or color them) such the question is unambiguous.

Comment: There are three mu nodes. The first is connected to [t] and [a] and the third is connected to [k] and [a]. I want to add a line (\draw (mu2) -- (k)) connecting the second mu and [k].   This works in other trees which don't use level = 4{fit=band}  but here the line is not drawn.

Comment: Sorry, in your second, i.e. right, tree there are three `mu`s, and the second one (counting from left to right) is connected to `k`. What am I missing?

Comment: When I compile this the mu is not connected to k

Comment: You have two trees with a total number of five `mu`s. It is very hard to communicate in this way. What is "the mu" in "the mu is not connected to k", i.e. which of the five (!) `mu`s are you referring to?

Comment: sorry - the second mu in the second tree is not connected to the k when I compile this. I was referring to the same mu that you were referring to so I thought "the mu" was explicit. This is my first post here - can I add a pdf of the compiled version? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Then the difference is conceivably related to the TeX installation. I do get a connection between the `mu` which you gave the name `mu2`, i.e. the second from left in the second tree, with `k` on my updated TeXLive 2020 installation.

Comment: OK I'll try updating

Comment: In general it helps to post a screen shot of the result and perhaps also add an annotation to make the question clear.

Comment: TexShop 4.44 is currently the most recent version available....

Comment: TeXShop is an *editor*, not a TeX installation.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance - and I don't know how to post a screen shot

Comment: OK I updated my TeXLive installation to 2020 and the problem is solved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments by updating TeX.